# can't export .pdf_tex file in inkscape 1.3

Tags: svg, text, cairo, inkscape

when i want to export a svg file to `.pdf` and `.pdf_tex` file. I do `Save As-PDF` and select `Omit text in PDF and create latex file`, Finaly, i can't get the `.pdf_tex` file. But it works on my WSL-Inkscape with the same `.svg` file.

Here is the inkscape system info under windows:

```
Inkscape 1.3 (0e150ed6c4, 2023-07-21)

    GLib version:     2.76.4
    GTK version:      3.24.38
    glibmm version:   2.66.6
    gtkmm version:    3.24.7
    libxml2 version:  2.11.4
    libxslt version:  1.1.38
    Cairo version:    1.17.7
    Pango version:    1.50.14
    HarfBuzz version: 8.0.1

    OS version:       Windows 11 22H2
```

Here is some attempts i have make:

- Check if svg file error

At first, i just think this is a file error, font style setting error For example.Then i use the file works well in WSL-Inkscape, this error still exists in Windows. The test file can be downloaded at [test.svg](https://github.com/zongpingding/File_Exchange/blob/main/Test.svg).

- Try to Debug

I start inkscape in powershell

```bash
set GTK_DEBUG=interactive
inkscape
```

Then do the process as before, then Inkscape throw an warning message:

```
** (org.inkscape.Inkscape:12388): WARNING **: 12:14:51.983: Duplicate option text ('RGBA 8') for parameter 'png_bitdepth' in extension 'org.inkscape.output.png.inkscape'.

** (org.inkscape.Inkscape:12388): WARNING **: 12:15:22.990: Could not set value ('') for parameter 'textToPath' in extension 'org.inkscape.output.pdf.cairorenderer'. Not a valid choice.
```

as far as i see, the second is the main reason, for the first message is in the debug info of wsl-inkscape that works well. Then i search google for the second warning message, but i get nothing.I also search the aforementioned extension `org.inkscape.output.pdf.cairorenderer` but i still find nothing in the inksacpe installation folder, so do the the parameter `textToPath`.

Who can help me, Thanks a lot.

- Additionally

export `.pdf_tex` works well using command line by the following cmd:

```bash
inkscape -D --export-latex --export-filename=Test.pdf Test.svg
```

Who can help me, Thanks a lot.